# Google Font rendering in IE7

Tags: fonts, embedded-fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm finding some inconsistency when using the Google Fonts on my site.

I'm importing `Arvo Regular` and Bold into my site and find that IE 7 is not rendering the fonts as I would expect every time.  The first example is how I want it to display.

**Example 1**

[image: Example 1]

The second example seems to be loading the font, but instead the regular variant.  It seems to be random which version will display each time.

**Example 2**

[image: Example 2]

As you would figure I want it to display like example 1 every time instead of it being a gamble that it will actually load the proper font each time.

Comment: I believe I discovered what the problem is.  For some reason when I would import the Arvo font from Google and specify regular and bold it would cause this issue.  Seemed to randomly pick to render the regular or bold fonts instead of just the bold font.  I ended up changing it so that it only imports the bold font and it seems to have fixed my problem.  I attempted using a fontsquirrel kit to embed the fonts, but for some reason it refused to render the bold as well as the Google Font did.

Comment: If you want to use the regular and bold, import both, but create a specific class for each one. For example, you may have the `.bold` and `.regular` class. You would just put your text in your site like this. `<bold>Bold and </bold><regular>regular font weights</regular>`